# angularjs ng-click breacks after second click

Tags: angularjs, click, ng-bind

to show you my problem, here a link

http://codepen.io/destroy90210/pen/adbCy

if you click on the button the first time it fades up and the form will be shown,
if i click on reset then the form get closed, but now if i want to open it again nothing happens, it seems that the function "openForm()" never get called again.

does anybody knows why??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function and bool have the same name, `$scope.openForm`  You are overriding the function to `false` on the close event (as well as `true` on the open).

```
$scope.openForm = false;            // <--- $scope.openForm is being set to a bool
$scope.openForm = function() {      // <--- $scope.openForm is being set to a function
    $scope.openForm = true;         // <--- $scope.openForm is being set to a bool
    console.log($scope.openForm);
}

$scope.closeForm = function() {
    $scope.openForm = false;        // <--- $scope.openForm is being set to a bool
    console.log($scope.openForm);
}
```

Solution, use a different name for the bool

```
$scope.isFormOpen = false;
$scope.openForm = function() {
    $scope.isFormOpen = true;
    console.log($scope.isFormOpen);
}

$scope.closeForm = function() {
    $scope.isFormOpen = false;
    console.log($scope.isFormOpen);
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tGwAI

Comment: Thanks a lot...same thing happened with me